# htaccess replace "_" with "-"

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my `htaccess` which hides `?m` from URL.

```
RewriteEngine On

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?m=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

One example of `$1` might be `my_profile`. Now I want users to see it as `my-profile`, but in `PHP` the value of `$_GET['m']` should still be `my_profile`. How can I do this ?

Comment: Is it necessary that stuff like `my_extremely_fancy_profile` must work?

Comment: If it is `my_extremely_fancy_profile` to the user it should be shown like `my-extremely-fancy-profile `, but in `PHP` it should still be `my_extremely_fancy_profile`.

Comment: well then I would recommend you to let the user call `my-extremely-fancy-profile` and replace it in the php: `$getM = str_replace('-','_',$_GET['m']);`

Comment: Yes I know I can do that in PHP but how do I replace "_" with "-" in `htaccess`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so if I get your request correctly you are calling: `mydomain.com/my-profile` then the following will work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*-.*) $1_$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ index.php?m=$1_$2 [L]
```

Comment: Did it work as expected?

Comment: Yes it works, but actually I did it the way you suggested in the comment. The link is `my-profile` and I replace in PHP all "-" with "_".